# Gambit enumpoly output documentation

Tags: game-theory

Looking for documentation of the output from
gambit-enumpoly

I am writing code that reads this in, and I would like a description of
the order of the output, preferably with examples.
IN
http://www.gambit-project.org/gambit14/tools.html#command-line
there is one example invocation output
    gambit-enumpoly e01.efg
but I can find no explanation nor can I find a listing of e01.efg

I searched extensively in Gogle and in 
stderr.org/doc/gambit-doc/html

Dr. Laurence Leff  Western Illinois University, Macomb IL 61455 ||(309) 298-1315
Stipes 447 Assoc. Prof. of Computer Sci. Pager: 309-367-0787 FAX: 309-298-2302